# Updating an element of a components style in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs, jsx

I have a custom component called CardSection

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const CardSection = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    position: 'relative'
  }
};

export { CardSection };
```

When I instantiate this component from another class I would like to update one of the style elements while the others remain unchanged. The code below will only update the justifyContent element.

```
  <CardSection style={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
```

The solution I have at the minute does not seem to be working and I would like to avoid duplicating the element with just a change to one of the style elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
//destruct props
const CardSection = ({ style, children }) => {
  return (
    // prop 'style' overrides standard containerStyle
    <View style={[styles.containerStyle, style]}>
      {children}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge styles if you pass an array to `styles`:

```
const CardSection = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.containerStyle, props.style]}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
};
```

They 'cascade' from left to right, meaning that latter styles in the array overwrite the former.

[Here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html) is the documentation for styling in react-native by default.